# Using Authorize Users works but not Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone help me, when I use Authorize Users in my controller is works just fine, but not Authorize roles (see code below). It prompts me for a username password every group I test. And it will not even let me in when entering domain administrator as the user.  When using roles it prompts me for:  connecting to (mycomputer name).domain name.

Thanks,
EB

```
        [Authorize(Users = @"domain\User")]

        [Authorize(Roles= "Intranet-Users")]
```

Comment: You need to prefix your domain for your groups as well.

Comment: Yes I have tries that still same issue..